# appendqueryparams is deprecated in ios 7

Tags: ios, ios7, nsstring, deprecated

Im facing this warning in ios7
[image]

I cant find the solution in google.Can you guide me to solve this warning.

Comment: The method you needed is deprecated in iOS 7. So we need to choose an alternate for it. my i know what actually you are trying to append over there.

Comment: `appendQueryParams:` is not a method of `NSString` but part of an category of RestKit.  Make sure you import the `NSString+RestKit.h` header. An with the latest version of RestKit this method is replaced by `stringByAppendingQueryParameters:`. Make sure you have RestKit in your project.

Comment: NSString+RestKit.h not found..

Comment: Do you have ResKit setup corectly in your project ?

Comment: Yes Already project is running now im converting it to iOS 7.

Comment: check the file in your build phase and lib too and clean your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `stringByAppendingQueryParameters` Instead of `appendQueryParams` Because `appendQueryParams` is deprecated in RestKit.